# Proper use of the word "consequently"

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know whether the word "Consequently" can be followed by a verb without being separated by a comma!  For instance, "His actions consequently led to the destruction of that beautiful car!"

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Use it in good health.

Comment: Note that there are two senses which 'consequently' can carry: << **Adv. 1.** consequently - (sentence connectors) _because of the reason given [in the previous sentence etc]_ ; "consequently, he didn't do it"; "continued to have severe headaches and accordingly returned to the doctor" accordingly // **2.** consequently - _as a consequence_ ; "he had good reason to be grateful for the opportunities which they had made available to him and which consequently led to the good position he now held" therefore >> (Based on ...

Comment: [WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection. © 2003-2012 Princeton University, Farlex Inc.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consequently) ) and that some might prefer the commas to ensure that the pragmatic marker (sentence connector) usage is understood. But I think that the true adverb usage would be redundant with 'led to'. –

Answer (score 3):

The word 'consequently' has two meanings, as highlighted earlier.

According to the [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consequently);

> 1. Consequently (adverb): As a result; therefore.
> 2. Consequently (sentence connector): as a result or effect; therefore; hence

1. The first form of the word 'consequently' is generally followed by a verb, normally without a comma.

E.g.

> Since then, I have consequently become a Princeton professor.
>
> Tomorrow, I will consequently write my GCSE Examination.

As Edwin Ashworth said in a comment, this form is best paraphrased by 'inevitably'.

This form of 'consequently' is not usually followed by a comma.

2. In the second form of consequently, the word is almost always followed by a comma, followed by the pronoun 'it', or any other noun (or its equivalents like other pronouns).

E.g.

> - A prism looks like four triangles joined edge to edge. Consequently, it has four vertices and six edges.
> - I am not as good as Robert at kayaking; consequently, I must practise more than him.
> - Kelly was smarter than Martin; consequently, Martin needed to prove his worth to his master.

- I am in lockdown because of the present coronavirus pandemic, and consequently, I need my daughter to do a weekly shopping run.
- I can't work and consequently I can't pay my bills.

Again, as user Edwin Ashworth said in a comment, it is best paraphrased by 'for this reason'.

This form of the word is generally followed by a comma, though as the last example shows, this is not a strict rule. Note that the main clauses are short in that example. If there is the usual comma after this form of *consequently*, there will always be *heavy-duty* punctuation immediately before it (a semicolon etc, or full stop) or *some* punctuation before the 'and' (usually a comma).

Comment: You fail to pick up on the two usages of 'consequently': (a) the pragmatic marker paraphrasing 'for the reason/s just given' // (b) the adverb meaning 'as a direct result of the situation just described'. (a) sometimes works where (b) doesn't.

Comment: (a) 'He was very frugal; consequently, he always used the bus rather than a taxi.' (not a direct result – he was still free to take a taxi any time he liked. Paraphrased by 'for this reason'.) (b) 'The fire had too good a hold –  the factory was consequently destroyed.' (an inevitable consequence. Paraphrased by 'inevitably'.)