# Commas after and before 'and consequently'

Tags: commas

I have the following sentence and I need your help:

"The study shows the good results of Method A(,) and consequently(,) the need to apply optimization approaches."

Do I need the two commas there? Grammarly tells me to put commas there? I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: The sentence is probably infelicitous as it stands. 'The study shows the good results of Method A(,) and consequently indicates that it may well be that applying optimization approaches is the best way forward.'  Would 'The studies show that the COVID-19 infection rate has not plateaued yet(,) and consequently(,) the Government has not relaxed lockdown measures' do as an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper use of the word "consequently"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377614/proper-use-of-the-word-consequently)

Comment: Thanks Edwin for your answer. No, the link does not answer my question. According to Grammarly I have to use commas right before and right after consequently. However in the sentence "Demand response limits the peak load and consequently the stress on grid components" no commas are required. I do not see the difference between the sentences

Comment: Try @Abhigyan Chattopadhyay's answer as now augmented. << 'I am in lockdown because of the present coronavirus pandemic, and consequently, I need my daughter to do a weekly shopping run.' / 'I can't work and consequently I can't pay my bills.'
Again, as user Edwin Ashworth said in a comment, it is best paraphrased by 'for this reason'.

This form of the word is generally followed by a comma, though as the last example shows, this is not a strict rule. Note that the main clauses are short in that example....

Comment: If there is the usual comma after this form of consequently, there will always be heavy-duty punctuation immediately before it (a semicolon etc, or full stop) or punctuation before the 'and' (usually a comma). >>

Comment: Thanks Edwin for your answers. So whenenver I can replace it by 'for this reasons' there should be commas like this: ', and consequently,...'. Is that correct?

Comment: The answer there is pretty detailed, and includes << I can't work and consequently I can't pay my bills. >> among acceptable examples.

Comment: Thanks Edwin for your answer. In my example 'consequently' is not an adverb and still I have to use the commas whereas in the example '"Demand response limits the peak load and consequently the stress on grid components"' the word 'consequently' is also not an adverb but here I should not use the commas according to Grammarly and Machavity (see comments below in the answer). I do not see the difference between these sentences

Comment: I've said that I find your original sentence borderline unacceptable. If acceptable, the commas would be optional there too, in spite of opinions to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

"consequently" is an [conjunction](https://www.iup.edu/writingcenter/writing-resources/grammar/common-problems-with-however,-therefore,-and-similar-words/), so it really needs to be wrapped by commas. You don't need a comma after "Method A"

> The study shows the good results of Method A and `,`consequently`,` the need to apply optimization approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Machavity. Do I always have to wrap 'consequently' by commas? For example in this sentence Grammarly tells me that I don't need commas: "Demand response limits the peak load and consequently the stress on grid components"

Comment: No. The key there is to take `consequently` out and see how it reads. The sentence in your comment cannot stand by itself without the word, so it doesn't need commas, while the one in your question can

Comment: Thanks Machavity for your comment. Why can the sentence of my comment not stand by itself without consequently. The sentence would be: "Demand response limits the peak load and the stress on grid components". According to my point of view this is totally fine. I even think that I have read this several times in the literature

Comment: Ah. I misread it. You're right, it does. I forgot something important there: [consequently has two meanings](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/377618) They're very similar so it's easy to confuse which needs a comma and which does not

Comment: Thanks Machavity for your answer. I still do not see the difference between my two sentences. Also the link does not help much. Why do I have to use commas for the one sentence and not for the other. For me, they are equal. They are not adverbs in both cases (when I stick to the link you posted; which, as said before, does not help me at all)

Comment: I still do not see the difference between my two sentences